# Database Re-engineering/Schema Generator Tools

Tags: oracle, database-design, reverse-engineering

I have joined a project which has been already developed and its a legacy project with very large database and its in Java/J2EE.

I am trying to understand the Database Design & Architecture and so is there a tool available which can generate schema from the populated table representing all the constraints like foreign keys etc ?

Basically am looking for an Database Re-engineering Tool. My database is **Oracle 10g**.

Inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use ER/Studio and I absolutely love it for all my data modeling, reverse engineering and database design work.

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio

I should really become an ER/Studio evangelist.. but really, it is a great product.

Comment: +1 - I'd describe ER/Studio as the best of a bad lot - it seems to have the best coverage of Oracle features.  Also, if by "large database" you mean lots of objects rather than data size, than some of the other tools (I'm looking at you, SQL Developer) simply fall over when asked to reverse-engineer.

Comment: Thank you Raj. I will download the trial version and try to work around with it.

Comment: Another upvote for ER/Studio.  Worth its weight in gold for its ability to take a logical data model, analyze an actual database, then emit the DDL to update the database to match the logical model.  Automated the most tedious and error-prone aspect of rolling out a new release for us.  Bonus points for doing it for both Oracle and SQL Server with the same logical data model.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't played much with it, but Oracle has a tool included with SQL Developer: [Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler.](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html#) I agree with @Raj that ER Studio is very good; I've also used [ERWin](http://www.ca.com/us/products/product.aspx?ID=260). Both have the drawback of being quite pricey. For a while there was free downloads, but I see now it appears they're charging for it. Don't know how much.

Comment: How can we generate schema diagrams using SQL Developer ?

Comment: There is a separate component in the suite called Data Modeler. They do charge for it now, and it appears to be in the same ballpark price-wise as the other tools. You can download and evaluate it however.